# Create a new Databricks cluster using Python SDK

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-python-sdk

I am trying to create a new Azure Databricks cluster using the Databricks Python SDK and I run into the following problem:

I need an Init Script for my cluster and when I am trying to set this property in code, I get the following error:

TypeError: 'InitScriptInfo' object is not iterable

For the cluster log conf property, same type of code works perfectly.

Create code is below. Do you have any ideas about how can I setup the InitScript in Pyhton SDK?

```
from databricks.sdk import WorkspaceClient
from databricks.sdk.service.compute import AutoScale, ClusterSource, DataSecurityMode,RuntimeEngine, ClusterLogConf, DbfsStorageInfo,InitScriptInfo, WorkspaceStorageInfo
w = WorkspaceClient(
  host  = workspace_host,
  token = workspace_token
)
c = w.clusters.create_and_wait(
  cluster_name              = 'TEST',
  spark_version             = '12.2.x-scala2.12',
  node_type_id              = 'Standard_D4s_v3',
  autotermination_minutes   = 15,
  num_workers               = 2,
  autoscale                 = AutoScale(min_workers=2, max_workers=4),
  cluster_log_conf          = ClusterLogConf(DbfsStorageInfo('dbfs:/cluster-logs')),
  init_scripts              = InitScriptInfo(WorkspaceStorageInfo('/Shared/filename.sh'))
)
```

Thank you

Comment: As per the [link](https://databricks-sdk-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/workspace/clusters.html) the init scripts option accepts a list of InitScriptInfo objects - `init_scripts – List[InitScriptInfo] (optional)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to replicate the issue with your code in my environment, I got the same error:

[image]

The error you're getting, `'InitScriptInfo' object is not iterable`, indicates that you are trying to iterate over an object that is not iterable, which means the object does not support iteration using a loop. I modified the code as mentioned below:

```
 init_scripts=[InitScriptInfo(WorkspaceStorageInfo('Filepath'))]
```

I tried to execute the code it executed successfully without any error:

[image]

The cluster created successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help, it is working. Just a small thing. Is it possible to indicate that init scripts source it is the Workspace? Seems that by default it goes to DBFS, whatever path I am writing in code. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can do it.

Comment: Do you know how? I was expecting that WorkspaceStorageInfo to set directly a workspace type init script. Am I missing something here? Than kyou

Comment: I've figgure it out. I need to put all other storage types (S3, DBFS) on None and then it will create it with Workspace type.                                                                        
Like: [InitScriptInfo(S3StorageInfo(None), DbfsStorageInfo(None),WorkspaceStorageInfo('/Shared/filename.sh'))]